quarto pdf figure layout by column
Is it possible to natively define the figure layout in quarto by column instead of row as in the example below? I would like to have image1 and image2 in one column on the left side and image3 in a separate column on the right side. Additionally, image3 shouldn't be aligned to the bottom of image2, but appear centered in regards to the combined height of image1 and image2.
::: {#fig-group_label layout="[[0.5,0.5],[1]]"}
![](image1.png){#fig-label1}

![](image2.png){#fig-label2}

![](image3.png){#fig-label3}

caption
:::

layout-ncol=2 doesn't properly hande the tags of the images, only (a) is displayed below the first image, while (b) and (c) are missing.
:::{#fig-group_label layout-ncol=2}

![](image1.png){#fig-label1}

![](image2.png){#fig-label2}
![](image3.png){#fig-label3}

caption
:::

This layout also doesn't display the figure labels properly, only (a) is displayed.
:::{#fig-group_label layout="[[100],[60,40]]"}

![](image1.png){#fig-label1}

![](image2.png){#fig-label2}
![](image3.png){#fig-label3}

caption
:::


This works as expected:
:::: {#fig-group_label layout="[0.5, 0.5]"}

:::{#firstcol}

![](image1.png){#fig-label1}

![](image2.png){#fig-label2}

:::

:::{#secondcol}
![](image3.png){#fig-label3}

:::

::::


